# What word to use to describe the opposite of a distribution's tail?

Tags: terminology

I'm currently writing a paper. Without getting into too many details, in one section I talk about the distribution of a certain observable of a Markov Process:

> The tail of each distribution is fit well by a single exponential distribution, but...

What I want to be able to say is that the rest of the distribution is not fit well by any reasonable mixture of exponentials, but I can't think of the right word.

What do I call the rest of the distribution aside from the tail? The body? The bulk? Is there an accepted term for this?

Comment: You could refer to it as the center of the distribution. As  "tail" is not a very precisely defined term you could term it as the opposite of the object you define as the tail. Or, in case you have some precise measures you could refer to it in terms of quantiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of an exponential or something clearly one-sided (that is, with only a single tail) like that I'd say "body" or "bulk" quite happily, just as you suggest.

In cases where there's two tails, not too far from symmetric and I want to distinguish from both tails I might say "center" or "middle", but I might still say "body".

Comment: +1. I had reason to choose an informal term for this very recently and chose "clump", as in _main clump_. Note that no terminology matches all possibilities: witness comb distributions (a series of spikes of equal probability) or U-shaped distributions. But just as no one need say precisely where tails stop and start, usually a meaningless question, so also any term should be treated loosely .

Comment: (As is usually the case) I agree with all that you said there.